# use data stored in scope variable instead of making an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, css

I am using angular-datatable with table tools [link](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withTableTools).

view.html

```
<table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Data</th>
               </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
        <td>{{ data.Id }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.Name }}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

controller.js (I have injected DTOptionsBuilder and DTColumnBuilder in the controller)

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
    .withTableTools('app/bower_components/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')
    .withTableToolsButtons([
        'copy',
        'print', {
            'sExtends': 'collection',
            'sButtonText': 'Save',
            'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
        }
    ]);
```

In app.js, I have included datatables and datatables.tabletools.

In index.html, I have included

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/datatables-tabletools/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/angular-datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/datatables-tabletools/js/dataTables.tableTools.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-datatables/dist/plugins/tabletools/angular-datatables.tabletools.min.js"></script>
```

I want to use the data used in scope variable instead of making an ajax call. If I remove the fromSource(data.json), I am getting an error that tableTools is not a function. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the documentation and there is a `withPromise` which can be used

```
 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() { return $q.when($scope.yourObject);})
    .withTableTools('app/bower_components/datatables-tabletools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf')
    .withTableToolsButtons([
        'copy',
        'print', {
            'sExtends': 'collection',
            'sButtonText': 'Save',
            'aButtons': ['csv', 'xls', 'pdf']
        }
    ]);
```

Try it.

`$q.when` returns a promise which resolves to the value passed in as parameter to `when` function.